# c# datatable filter using like operator

Tags: c#, wpf

```
dtjr.DefaultView.RowFilter = " Journal_Name Like '" + cbo_jrnl.Text.Trim() + "*'";
```

is working fine,

But i want to filter all `jounral_name` starts with number from **0-9**

How could i achieve this ?

Comment: You're going to need to expand on this question and show some code. It is difficult to tell what you want.

Comment: I made an edit to include the range of numbers between 0 and 9. This makes the query a little simpler. Have a look

Answer (score 2):

what you need is the `%` operator:

```
dtjr.DefaultView.RowFilter = " Journal_Name Like '" + cbo_jrnl.Text.Trim() + "%'";
```

Here is a [lesso with examples](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) to the usage of `LIKE`

And here us the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql) explanation for the syntax and usage:

```
Wildcard character    Description           Example

      %               Any string of zero    WHERE title LIKE '%computer%' 
                      or more characters.   finds all book titles with 
                                            the word 'computer' anywhere in 
                                            the book title.
```

EDIT:

Sorry for the lack of attention. if as you say:

> But i want to filter all `jounral_name` starts with number from **0-9**

In this case unfortunately using the `[ ]` operator ( which is also described in the MSDN link I posted) to state a range of numbers will not work as it seems to be the wrong format. What you can do is to check the range by comparison `<` and `>` and using the wildcard:

```
dtjr.DefaultView.RowFilter = @"Journal_Name > '0%' AND Journal_Name < '9%'";
```

Comment: RowFilter doesn't work like TSQL! - "Wildcard characters are not allowed in the middle of a string. For example, 'te*xt' is not allowed." - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_DataColumn_Expression

Comment: @KakhaMiddleOr thank you for your comment, I don't quite understand how it relates because I don't use the wildcard in the middle of a string, but I double checked and it turnes out, that the range checking of numbers with the `[ ]` brackets does not work. So I made an edit and posted a different, tested and working solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not using `like` keyword here but You can use  `Regex` and `linq` as below to achieve your goal

```
    dtjr= dtjr.AsEnumerable()
     .Where(r => Regex.IsMatch(r["jounral_name"].ToString(), "^[0-9]+"))
     .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Welcome @shashisampige

Comment: @shashisampige the best way to thank on StackOverflow is [to mark the answer that helped you as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)